# Reading Multiline Description Field and Adding Fields to a SQL Database Depending on the Description Field Values

Tags: string, .net

Here's what I'm trying to do.

- Select Cases Where Status = New.
- Read the multiline Description field.
- Add the Case Id, Subject, Description to the database requests table.
- Depending on the Description

  - If it contains Port - Yes then Add Yes or true to the Port field in the db and add the Port Number to the Port Number field.
  - If it contains New - Yes then Add Yes or true to the New field in the db and add the New Number to the New Number field.

Here's my code.

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        var client = await SalesforceService.GetUserNamePasswordForceClientAsync();

        var accounts = await client.QueryAsync<Case>("SELECT Id, Subject, Description FROM Case Where Status='New'");
        var sfAccounts = accounts.Records.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Id,
            c.Subject,
            c.Description
        });

        var request = new Request();
        List<Request> requestresults = new List<Request>();

        foreach (var c in sfAccounts)
        {
            if (c.Description != null)
            {
                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(c.Description))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        //s.Split('-');
                        if (line.StartsWith("Port"))
                        {
                            request.Port = line;
                            requestresults.Add(request);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(requestresults);
```

Although the requestresults contains two records only one is being returned. 
My Request Class

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Contact ID")]
    [Createable(false), Updateable(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string PortNumber { get; set; }
    public string New { get; set; }
    public string NewNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Sample Description - Each field is on a new line
Port - Yes /n
Number - 9781234567 /n
New - Yes /n
New Number - 9786543210

Comment: whats the issue you are facing? what specific thing you are looking for from community members?

Comment: My first question is why is the requestresults returning only one case when there are two cases when I go into it while debugging. Here are the results. [{"$id":"1","Id":null,"Port":"Port - Yes","PortNumber":null,"New":null,"NewNumber":null},{"$ref":"1"}]

Comment: @LauraBejjani Are you saying that the size of `accounts` doesn't match `sfAccounts` when debugging? Are you debugging it as the same Salesforce user?

Comment: @DanielBallinger - I'm saying the return Ok(requestresults) should be returning 2 records (cases). It contains two cases. The count is 2 but it's only printing one.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - It's only returning the last case.